# Anchor Tag Issue while opening a browser Pop up

Tags: javascript, html

```
viewresident = '<a href="javascript:;" onclick="return openPopup(' + viewUrl + ');" >' + name[i] + '</a>';
```

I am using JQ Grid to set this to the Name row of the grid.There are no errors, but the page doesn't open up a popup in a new window. Please let me know wat's wrong.

```
function openPopup(url) {
      window.open(url, "popup_id", "scrollbars,resizable");
      return false;
    }
```

The whole thing is written in JS.

Answer (score 1):

Read how to use `window.open()`: [Window open() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp), then try this:

```
viewresident = '<a href="javascript:openPopup(' + viewUrl + ');" >' + name[i] + '</a>';

function openPopup(url){
    window.open(url,'Popup','scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, width=500, height=400');
}
```

`scrollbars=no` disables window scrollbars and `resizable=no` disables window resizing.